# Best way to replace an existing user with new user

Tags: administration, user-management

We have an employee who left the organization and a new one one replacing him. What is the best way to assign all the records owned by the previous user to the new user? The new user is performing the same role as the old one.

What is the best practice?

2 options i can think off

1. Change the old users user record to the new user
2. Deactivate the old user and create a new user and then go about changing ownership

Answer (score 4):

I would only ever do No. 2 because every single audit history record is then going to be against the new user even though the old user did it. Yep, it's more of a PITA, but if you are in a heavily regulated industry you are going to need a clean audit trail, and you should have that no matter the size of your org.

Comment: yeah i agree.. Maybe couple of hours of more work but definitely the cleanest